# I'm sending character email '.' And I'm receiving angular js cakephp '_'

Tags: angularjs, cakephp, post

I'm sending character email '.' And I'm receiving angular js cakephp '_'

Can someone tell me why?

My method

```
  $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8765/api/v1/users/oauth.json?token=' + t1 + '&redirect_url=localhost:8765/api/v1/users/',
        data:  user,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                "X-Login-Ajax-call": 'true',
                'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
              }
      })
        .success(function (data) {
          console.log('sucesso segundo token ' + data)
        })
        .error(function (responde) {
          console.log('erro segundo token ' + responde)
        })
```

my objct user

```
  var user = {
    email: ciro.sda@gmail.com,
    password: bruae
  }
```

My post return

```
["{"email":"ciro_sda@gmail_com","password":"bruae"}"]
```

Comment: Hi, in Content-Type you should use ''application/json''

Comment: Could you post the controller action code

Comment: Could you inspect the browser's network and get the request body? I think that the problem is on php and not in this js.

Comment: Marcos Nunes, 
I've specified my network and it's like this ...
array(3) { ["{"email":"ciro_sda@gmail_com","password":"123456"}"]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(18) "ciro_sda@gmail_com" ["password"]=> string(6) "123456" }

I have no idea why